# Lua advanced recursion Getting children's children

Tags: recursion, lua

I have code like this

```
local tbl = {
    IsNativeUI = true
}

tbl2 = {
    IsNativeUI = false,
    _Children = {},
    
    GetChildren = function(self)
        return self._Children
    end

}

tbl3 = {
    IsNativeUI = false,
    _Children = {},
    
    GetChildren = function(self)
        return self._Children
    end
}

tbl4 = {
    IsNativeUI = false,
    _Children = {},
    
    GetChildren = function(self)
        return self._Children
    end
}

table.insert(tbl2._Children, tbl3)
table.insert(tbl3._Children, tbl4)

function GetAncestry(tbl)
    -- Gets all the table's children and their children and so forth until IsNativeUI is false
    
end
```

I've spent a few hours on this, but I can't get it.. What i'm wanting to do is when I call GetAncestry(tbl4), it will get all the childrens of the children until the IsNativeUI is false.

If someone could help me please I would really appreciate it

Edit: (the _Children table could also be empty)

Comment: what have you tried? this is not a coding service show some own attempt

Comment: Start with a non-recursive case of returning all direct children of `tbl`, then make it recursive. If you get stuck with that, make another (more specific) question about that :D